# Android Static vs Shared Library

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an android project which consists of a java file and two ndk libraries one C++ and other JNI. JNI shared library loads the C++ static lib and call one of it's method. Here are all the files..

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := Lib2
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Lib2.cpp
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := Lib1
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Lib1.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := Lib2
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Lib1.h**

```
#include <jni.h>
extern "C"
    {
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_mine_twocpplibtest_TwocpplibtestActivity _TestMethod(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj);
    };
```

**Lib1.cpp**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "Lib1.h"
#include "Lib2.h"
using namespace Lib2ns;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_mine_twocpplibtest_TwocpplibtestActivity_TestMethod(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{
    Lib2::TestChanged();
}
```

**Lib2.h**

```
#ifndef Lib2_HEADER
#define Lib2_HEADER

using namespace std;

namespace Lib2ns
{
    class Lib2
    {
        public:
            static void  TestChanged();
    };
}
#endif
```

**Lib2.cpp**

```
#include "Lib2.h"
using namespace Lib2ns;

void Lib2::TestChanged()
{
}
```

This is my activity which loads Lib1

```
public class TwocpplibtestActivity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("Lib1");
    }
}
```

Problem is in `Android.mk` file when I define `Lib2` as `include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)` everything works fine but when I define `Lib2` as `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)` my activity crashes while trying to load the `Lib1`. Any ideas why this is so? Can't we have two shared libraries at a time in a project?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
static
{
    System.loadLibrary("Lib2");
    System.loadLibrary("Lib1");
}
```

Your apk must include libLib2.so as libLib1.so.

Comment: Lib2 actually was loaded? "Trying to load lib /data/data/mine.Twocpplibtest/lib/libLib2.so Added shared lib /data/data/mine.Twocpplibtest/lib/libLib2.so"

Comment: Nope, nothing in the log related to it

Answer (score 0):

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := Lib2

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Lib2.cpp

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := Lib1

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Lib1.cpp

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := Lib2

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

"Lib2" is a static library, you should use LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES